# HTML div should fully contain another div

Tags: html, css, image, slider, lightbox

my aim is to build a fullscreen overlay image slider using the slick slider by kenwheeler.

I already have the fullscreen overlay(div1) which an div(div2) inside and some margins around this div.

**Now to my problem:**
I want to put the slider(div3) into div2 independent of the size of div2.
If the slider is more in width and less in height, there should be a bigger distance on top and on bottom; If the slider is more in height and less in width, there should be a bigger distance on the left and on the right.

That's what I already have:

```css
#div1{
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 
 z-index: 9999;
 
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
#div2{
 margin: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: green;
    
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
#div3{
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 
  background: blue;
}
#div3 div{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#div3 div img{
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 
 height: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
   <div id="div3">
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P02.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P03.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P04.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P05.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P06.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P07.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P08.JPG" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="images/models/own/001_racecar/P09.JPG" alt=""></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know, that I am not very good in explaining. So, if you have questions, just ask me.
I hope that you can help me.

Thanks
Tobias Wälde

Comment: Hi Tobias, we need an example of your code in-order to help.

Comment: I edited my question and added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I got you wrong but what you want is to make sure that slider is always inside the parent div i.e. div2 in your case and div2 should grow with the content of slider. Am I right?

You can do it by using "container" class of bootstrap. I have made a simple jsfiddle for it. Let me know if it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/94kt3mwd/1/

```
<div id="div1" class="container col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" style= "background-color:#ff0;padding:2%">
  <div id="div2" class="container" style="background-color:#00f" align="center">
    <h1>
    HELLO! Add Text Here..
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.